# Is there a way to make nested for loops faster?

Tags: python, performance

Can anybody help to make this python code faster?

```
possible = {}
counter = 0
for a in range(0,8):
  for b in range(0,8):
    for c in range(0,8):
      for d in range(0,8):
        for e in range(0,8):
          for f in range(0,8):
            for h in range(0,8):
              for g in range(0,8):
                if not a+b==8 and c+d==8 and e+f==8 and h+g==8:
                  continue
                if not a+b+c+d+e+f+g == 64:
                  continue
                counter += 1
                possible[counter] = a,b,c,d,e,f,g

print(possible)
```

When I run this on [repl.it](https://repl.it), it shows me this error:

> repl process died unexpectedly: signal: killed

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why iterate through a **and** b if a+b must equal 8? Just iterate through a and set b = 8-a. Same for the other vars. Also, if each pair sums to 8 than the sum of all must be 32, not 64. Also, h seems to make an initial appearance and then seems forgotten.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Good point! Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: How could the sum of all values ever be `64`? There are 8 variables and each of those variables will have a maximum value of 7. Since `8 * 7` is `56` the task is pointless. So the fastest version will be `print({})`.